# Are all the tweeted links broken or just this one?

Tags: support

I was looking at https://writers.stackexchange.com/posts/17467/revisions where I noticed that the question had been tweeted. Cool but the #! in the tweet-link causes problems. Is this a common problem?

Comment: How does it cause problems? The link leads me to the Twitter page without problems.

Comment: with the #! I get the twitter home page, without it I get the tweet

Comment: The link works for me IFF I'm logged into Twitter.  When not logged in it takes me to the Twitter homepage.  This is on a desktop computer, not mobile.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, that explains it, as I don't have or want a twitter account.  I believe that I have looked at less than eight tweets ever. Just for giggles can we verify that http://twitter.com/StackWriters/status/603929073421840388 also works when you are logged in? Thanks.

Comment: That link works for me regardless of login status.  It seems like it would be better for the "tweeted" entries in the history to work for everybody, not just people logged in to Twitter.  I haven't paid much attention to those in the past so I don't know if it's always behaved this way or if it's a change.

Comment: so if we drop three characters we have a better user experience, cool, less Really is More

Comment: Why are those characters in the URL, if they don't work? I mean, who put them there and why? (The link with `#!` works for me on desktop but not on mobile, btw.) **Isn't there a canonical format for Twitter permalinks, and shouldn't we use that format, instead of guessing and trying what works where?**